# Float FancyBox?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I'm trying to develop a solution that will float FancyBox to the right of my content area (flush against the right margin).

The built in leftRatio parameter gets me close when set to 1, but it floats the box to the right of the viewport (rather than the content area).

I'm new to working with jQuery and trying to learn, so it would be great if you could explain things simply or point me to some documentation that would help me out.

Thanks so much for your help.

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying css on the `fancybox-wrap` element:

```
#fancybox-wrap {
    float: right;
}
```

(you might need to add `!important;`)

If that fails you could try the same but using jQuery:

```
$('#fancybox-wrap').css("float", "right");
```